# For loop skips values

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this program to recognize where an URL is within a message and leave in the string ONLY the URL, but it just skips values randomly and I din't know why. Here is my code and the debug console.

```
function DeleteNonURL(sep, URL)
{
    var _Pos = new Number;
    URL = URL.split(sep);
    for (var i = 0; i < URL.length; i++)//deletes non-url substrings
    {
    Debug.Trace("Msg: "+URL + " i: "+i + " _Pos: "+_Pos + " Current Substring: "+URL[i]);
        _Pos = URL[i].indexOf('.com');
        if(_Pos == -1)
        {
            _Pos = URL[i].indexOf('.net');
            if(_Pos == -1)
            {
                _Pos = URL[i].indexOf('.org');
                if(_Pos == -1)
                {
                    _Pos = URL[i].indexOf('.info');
                    if(_Pos == -1) //No URL in this substr
                    {
                        URL.splice(i, 1); //deleted.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Debug.Trace(URL);
}

Debug:
Msg: Hey,dude,look,at,this,amazon.com,what,is,it? i: 0 _Pos: 0 Current Substring: Hey

Msg: dude,look,at,this,amazon.com,what,is,it? i: 1 _Pos: -1 Current Substring: look

Msg: dude,at,this,amazon.com,what,is,it? i: 2 _Pos: -1 Current Substring: this

Msg: dude,at,amazon.com,what,is,it? i: 3 _Pos: -1 Current Substring: what

Msg: dude,at,amazon.com,is,it? i: 4 _Pos: -1 Current Substring: it?

dude,at,amazon.com,is
```

Comment: You are changing the length of the `URL` array in some cases (`URL.splice`), but you are always moving the index `i` (`i++`). You should not increment the index when you remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is the very common problem of mutating the array that you're iterating when the mutation causes the array to be reindexed.

Ultimately, you seem to be wanting to check for substring that ends with one of the TLDs. This can be done much more simply.

```js
const re = /\.(?:com|net|org|info)$/;

function test(sep, URL) {
    return URL.split(sep).find(s => re.test(s));
}

const a = "http://example.com/foo/bar";
const b = "foo/bar/baz";

console.log("TLD part", test('/', a));
console.log("TLD part", test('/', b));
```